# Stringify and parse an object literal

Tags: javascript

I have this object literal

```
var rides = {
  brand: {
    type: String,
    label: "搜尋",
    max: 100
  },
  model: {
    type: String,
    label: "Tìm kiếm",
    max: 100
  },
  fueltype: {
    type: String,
    label: "Пошук",
    allowedValues: ['Petrol', 'Diesel', 'Hybrid', 'Electric'],
  },
  bodystyle: {
    type: String,
    label: "بحث",
    allowedValues: ['Convertibles', 'Coupes', 'Hatchbacks', 'Vans', 'Sedans', 'Suvs', 'Trucks', 'Wagons'],
    optional: true
  },
  topspeed: {
    type: Number,
    label: "חיפוש",
    optional: true
  },
  power: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Power (HP)",
    optional: true
  }
};
```

which i have stringfied in this way

```
var ss = JSON.stringify(rides);
```

However, for what I am doing to work, I need to get the object i stringfied exactly the way it was before i stringfied

Thi is what it looks like https://jsfiddle.net/y37crsvd/1/

`Object { brand: Object, model: Object, fueltype: Object, bodystyle: Object, topspeed: Object, power: Object }`

How can I stringify the object literal so as to show the nested object properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `stringify()` functions, unless you use a custom revive parameter on `JSON.parse()`, and a custom mapper parameter on `JSON.stringify()`. Or, define `Function.prototype.toJSON` to get the "plain" `JSON.stringify()` to work with functions like `window.Number` and `window.String`.

Comment: Very subtle … although the loss of the type property isn't what the question *seems* to be asking about.

Answer (score 1):

The `xx` in the fiddle does contain the nested object properties, it's the console which requires you to expand the inner properties as well...

Answer (score 1):

When you log `xx` the console shows the object and allow you to expand the properties. It also puts the properties in alphabetic order.

If you do a `JSON.stringify(xx)` you will see exactly the same string as you input in the first time (properties in the same order...).